# SQL Server 2016 UTF-8 support of nvarchar columns?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, collation

I'm trying to figure out if my SQL Database setup is ready to store any language in the world (also Japanese). Having read a lot of documentation ([Microsofts own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2016#utf8)) I'm still unsure if further specification of collation is needed.

- Database: SQL Server Standard 2016
- Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Question: I have a table with a `MovieTitle` column, defined as `nvarchar(2048)`. Will this be able to store the movie title of any language in the world? According to the documentation it seems that any `nvarchar` column is UTF-8 from SQL Server version 2009.

I'm asking because recently I searched for

```
WHERE MovieTitle = ''
```

and it returns several results with different Arabic titles.

Comment: `nvarchar` is UTF-16, not UTF-8. UTF-8 support was added in SQL Server 2019, which is for `varchar` column (`nvarchar` columns would still be UTF-16). There's also no SQL Server 2009.

Comment: What you're seeing here isn't to do with what characters have (or haven't) been stored, it's how collation matching works. The `Latin1` collations do not do well for matching against things like Arabic characters.

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to compare **Unicode**-based strings in T-SQL, you **must use** the `N` prefix in front of your string literals (to indicate Unicode):
 `WHERE MovieTitle = N'..(your unicode characters).....'`

Comment: @marc_s: Is that relevant for `''`? I image that when comparing a varchar with an nvarchar, SQL Server will convert the varchar to nvarchar before comparing, right?

Comment: Technically it's not "relevant" for any string that doesn't contain any characters outside of the code page for the collation, @Heinzi , however, it's still good practice. Otherwise people get into the habit of omitting the `N` prefix when dealing with `nvarchar` literals and wondering why their code isn't working when they have a character outside of the code page.

Comment: @Larnu technically SQL Server uses UCS-2 in nchar, ntext and nvarchar columns unless the database is using an _SC (Supplementary Characters) collation, at which point most of the string functions are swapped out to be compatible with UTF-16 encoding. Microsoft provides a summary of the functional differences at [Collation and Unicode support # Supplementary characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#Supplementary_Characters).

Comment: @marc_s *Technically* speaking you could set your default collation to a UTF8 one, and then *not* use `N` but it's ill-advised

Comment: @Charlieface: but only in SQL Server **2019** - right? Earlier versions don't have any support for UTF-8, if I'm not mistaken ...

Comment: @marc_s Correct only 2019. UTF-8 support still has issues, and as Larnu says it can be confusing, so best avoided

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @marc_s its the same result with N''. So what do I do? Do I need to change the collation to support all languages? Do I need to use Sql 2019?